# Place to ask questions about product/service recommendations

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any place in the SE network where I can ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16322132/868044)?

> I'm looking for a PHP/MySQL form generator (free or paid) that meets the following specifications:
>
> Must generate HTML, CSS, MySQL statements, and PHP code (I can tweak as needed, but must get the basics including letting me specify DB field names)
>      Must have a visual form creator (I want to see what I'm creating)
>      Must be able to create professional-looking forms with quality CSS styling (no tables, some template/theme options would be good)
>      Must allow me to download all of the code (including supporting files such as CSS style sheets), I do not want the form nor data hosted on another platform (tools like WuFoo and JotForm let you embed the code, but don't seem to let me download everything)
>
> What tool(s)/service(s) will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 17):

No, there is no place on the network where product/service recommendations are allowed.

Comment: See also: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 4):

There are the various [chat sites around StackExchange](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) where you could bring this question up, but there's no guarantee anyone in there will have an ideal answer for you, but at least there should be people there that know about the tools so you could give that a try.